# Obtaining a BC year date stored in Postgres via JPA ignores the era

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, localdate

I'm working with BeforeChrist Era and I'm storing dates in PostgreSQL as a Date type and it works fine. The select query gives me this: `1001-01-01 00:00:00 BC` which is ok. In order to persist the date this way in the database, I pass `-1000-01-01` LocalDate Java 8 object to my JPA Entity: `@Column(nullable = false) private LocalDate date;` 
My problem is that when I'm getting this entity via JPA back from the database, it ignores "BC" completely and returns me my entity with the LocalDate date field of 1001-01-01 value, which is 2001 years after. How can I make JPA take that "BC" into account?

P.S. before I implemented the Converter, it was just `1001-01-01 BC` in the database, same BC-ignorance when getting the persisted entity back.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DateORMConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {


    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate attribute) {
        return attribute != null ? Date.valueOf(attribute) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : dbData.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check with `psql` if the date is stored correctly in the database. Then you know if you should search for the bug in the storage or in the retrieval code.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe "1001-01-01 00:00:00 BC" is what `psql` query returned me. I've looked it up via terminal in the `psql`.

Comment: So the problem is in the retrieval.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yep

Comment: Looks like a JDK bug. There are possible workarounds you could suggest the Hibernate team should implement.

Comment: I checked the code, and it's not fixed in the latest JDK repos either, so I sent a bug report. The JDK team can probably get to it in the next 6-7 years.

Comment: @coladict cool, I'll tell my PM that we need 7 years more for it =^__^= . Joking. Shall do additional columns for BC / AD eras.

Comment: I'll probably submit a workaround patch for Hibernate this week. It's simple enough.

Comment: it's easier to submit bug reports to the JDK now. Did someone report this already? If so, could you please share the bug id when one gets assigned?

Comment: @coladict can you please share the bug id with us, if you have one?

Comment: @Václav I didn't get a response with a JDK bug id, like I have with my other report to them. I guess it got ignored.